# Why don't Google Cloud Endpoints Support Simple Object Return Types?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Most of my methods return Strings, Integers, Booleans, etc and I bet that holds for 99% of developers, sure we sometimes return complex objects, arrays, etc. but most of the time something much simpler will do.

Why would Cloud Endpoints not support this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there are workarounds for returning "simple object types", in java you could return a StringResponse which would look something like this:

```
class StringResponse {
  String value;
  setter, getter... etc
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best possible workaround, I hope the authors of cloud endpoints see this and add in these very common data types, thanks for the answers, I'll mark this as the best answer to date.

Comment: I think they explicitly disallow those types.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are communicating with various programming languages that may or may not support the same data types. This is why most web API's will use something like XML or JSON as the data response type since it's standardized and parsable from any language.

Comment: What programming languages don't support basic data types like strings, ints, booleans, etc. Can you give me an example of where a POJO is supported, but a string or int is not?

Comment: No I can not give an example of a language that does not support one of those data types, but that's regardless. Not only would it be short-sighted to build an API assuming specific things about how someone may try to use/interface with them, but in all languages an "int"/Integer is not always the same. For example, and "Integer" data type in C++ is not/will not work the same as an "Integer" data type in Java, etc etc.

Comment: Just thought of an example... there's no such thing as a "String" in C programming language... one can emulate the idea/notion of a String, but it's not the same as the "String" in PHP for example... so that's just for starters.

Comment: Very true and I see where you're coming from on this, but POJOs don't exist in C either so they will have to deal with this issue one way or another. I wonder what the authors would say about this, they're hanging out here somewhere.