# generate String response from endpoints API method(java)

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am developing google endpoint API in that I got only POJO class response from API method.so
how can I get String or Integer,Float,boolean response from google endpoint API method?

Answer (score 0):

In the Endpoint methods, the return value type *cannot* be simple type such as String or int. The return value needs to be a POJO, an array or a Collection.

If you want some sort of a workaround for a String, look at this thread : [Why don't Google Cloud Endpoints Support Simple Object Return Types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703212/why-dont-google-cloud-endpoints-support-simple-object-return-types)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to create simple immutable value container classes (too bad we do not have scala support, you could just use case classes :P), eg

```
public final class StringHolder {
    private final String s;
    StringHolder(final String s) {
        this.s = Preconditions.checkNotNull(s, "null string input");
    }
    public String get() { return s; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StringHolder{" + "s='" + s + '\'' + '}';
    }

    // hashCode and equals are optional
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        final StringHolder that = (StringHolder) o;
        return s.equals(that.s);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return s.hashCode();
    }
}
```

The null check is optional, you may choose to allow nulls though in that case, you can even introduce a factory method and always return the same NullStringHolder instance in case of null inputs, which is leaner as it doesn't really have to hold data, just hardcore it to return null in get(). It would only make a difference if you happen to expect tons of nulls as a valid response (which is probably questionable).

Hope this helps!